# how to custom font to menu in divi builder?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add Marathi font to header menus.I failed to see option in divi builder(wordpress).

there are options, but they are only for default font's.

whats the procedure to add custom font for header menu in divi builder?

Comment: ok you need marathi menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this several times and the solution I employ is to install the Use Any Font plugin. You will need an API key and you can get that for free from the download page. If you use the free version, you will only be able to import one font. That can be found here:

Once you have your plugin installed, the API key active, and your font imported, you will need to target the nav links using CSS, as the plugin doesn't allow you to directly target the nav anchors. So, to achieve this add the following to your custom CSS panel:

```
.et_header_style_left #et-top-navigation nav > ul > li > a, .et_header_style_split #et-top-navigation nav > ul > li > a {
    font-family: Marathi, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add custom fonts in WordPress? Custom fonts can help you freshen up your theme and stand out. In this article, we will show you how to add custom fonts in WordPress using Google Fonts, TypeKit, and CSS3 @Font-Face method.

Load font and create class in css and add that class inside menu item,

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-fonts-in-wordpress/